# Pass click event on a view in a Fragment to the Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

I am trying to pass click event on a view in a `Fragment` to the `Activity`. I was following documentation guide from [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating#kotlin). 
As I understand it and I could be wrong but we need to create an interface, add a method declaration to it and trigger the method from when the click event is received on the Fragment. The Activity should then implement the interface defined in the fragment, so that the activity receives that event.

I have my Fragment:

```
class MoreFragment : Fragment() {

    internal var callback: OnMoreItemClickedListener

    fun setOnMoreItemClickedListener(callback: OnMoreItemClickedListener) {
        this.callback = callback
    }

    interface OnMoreItemClickedListener {
        fun onAddClothClicked()
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_more, container, false)
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()

        btn_add_clothes.setOnClickListener {
            callback.onAddClothClicked()
        }

    }
}
```

And I have my Activity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), MoreFragment.OnMoreItemClickedListener {

    override fun onAddClothClicked() {
        Log.d("MainActivity", "HERE")
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val navView: BottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)

        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
            setOf(
                R.id.navigation_clothes,
                R.id.navigation_seasons,
                R.id.navigation_notifications,
                R.id.navigation_more
            )
        )
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
        navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
    }

    override fun onAttachFragment(fragment: Fragment) {
        super.onAttachFragment(fragment)

        if(fragment is MoreFragment){
            fragment.setOnMoreItemClickedListener(this)
        }
    }
}
```

Now the error that I am getting is:

```
MoreFragment.kt: (16, 5): Property must be initialized or be abstract
```

`MoreFragment.kt: (16, 5)` is `internal var callback: OnMoreItemClickedListener`.The doc link above does suggest the same/ similar code but it does not work.

**Things that I have tried**

- I have tried putting a `lateinit var` for the `callback: OnMoreItemClickedListener` variable there but no luck. As it never gets initialized.
- I put `internal var callback: OnMoreItemClickedListener? = null` and referenced `callback` using the null safe operator `?.` but was not able to get the click event.

I am fairly new to Kotlin and Fragments too so please help me figure how to do  this. Thanks

Comment: is your problem resolved?

Comment: yes @KishanMaurya , accepted your answer. thanks

Comment: can you upvote it?

Comment: yes sure @KishanMaurya

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Fragment override onAttach method

```
private lateinit var callback: OnMoreItemClickedListener

    override onAttach(context : Context){
    callback  = context as OnMoreItemClickedListener
    }
```

then your callback will be init. as onAttach will be first. so no Property must be initialized or be abstract errror will occur.

also in Activity implement your interface(OnMoreItemClickedListener) and override its method. You will get callback

Comment: Also no need to override onAttachFragment() in activity. 
remove this method as well setOnMoreItemClickedListener

Answer (score 0):

Your both way is looks OK

> I have tried putting a lateinit var for the callback:
>
> I put internal var callback: OnMoreItemClickedListener? =
> null

I guess issue is here just debug below code. is it going inside `if`

```
if(fragment is MoreFragment){
  fragment.setOnMoreItemClickedListener(this)
}
```

Comment: Hey there, I put a `Log.d` there and indeed the `onAttachFragment(fragment: Fragment)` is not being called even when the `MoreFragment` is clicked on the BottonNav. I guess the Navigation Architecture Component does not work that way. Can you suggest any workaround?